# forward request from mainfolder to subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following file-structure :

- root folder

  - application folder ( non-public )
  - site folder

    - scripts-, styles- and image-folders ( public )
    - php include files folder ( non-public )
    - index.php
    - .htaccess ( for rewrite purposes )
  - other site folder ( admin, subdomain, ... )

    - scripts-, styles- and image-folders ( public )
    - php include files folder ( non-public )
    - index.php
    - .htaccess ( for rewrite purposes )
  - resources folder ( public )

The *application* folder is a folder with shared PHP-classes, only accessed by the local machine. The *resources* folder is accessible from everywhere, I store user-uploaded files there.

Every *site* folder has only 1 file who handles the request: *index.php* . The url *www.example.com/site/item/5* already gets rewritten by a .htaccess-file to *www.example.com/site/index.php?q=item/5*. The index-script works with the $_REQUEST["q"].

I can access every site folder directly by surfing to *www.example.com/site*, *www.example.com/admin* or *www.example.com/something*, as the all use their appropriate index-file.

**Now I only want to add some *.htaccess-file* in the root so www.example.com redirects to www.example.com/site, without breaking my mod_rewrite rules.**

If someone could please give me some advise, because the relevant things I tried were not working properly ( www.example.com/admin should still be accesible directly, ... )

If some addidiontal information is needed, I will provide it with pleasure.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /site [L,R]
```

This will redirect a request of `/` to `/site`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I actualy used.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ site/index.php [L,QSA]

Probably I can omit the last line by rewriting it a bit, but at least it is working as I expect!